# Random horizontal lines in Chrome when using table

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am seeing these random horizontal lines only in Chrome browser when I use tables. Interesting is that when I zoom out by 1 (mouse wheel tick) they disappear, when I zoom out 2, they appear again, then when I zoom out 3 "ticks" they disappear...

Any idea what attribute may I add to CSS to get rid of it?
[image]

*Please don't mind the text on the page, right now it's more or less equal to lorem ipsum.*

My CSS:

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100% !important;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

img{
    display:block !important;
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
    outline: none;
    }

img.bg {

  /* Set rules to fill background */
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;

  /* Set up proportionate scaling */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;

  /* Set up positioning */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

table td, tr {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: inspect them and see what html tag they are

Comment: Nothing. They appear they are not there in inspector. Or they are too thin to click.

Comment: Can you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Or, if you can't, put up a link to your website. You know, I googled...

Comment: It is not up yet. I can send you a file though if you provide me your email address. Or should I post the entire code here?

Comment: @OndrejTokar Not the entire code, no. Post the minimum required to replicate the issue; that is, snip away everything that isn't relevant.